# How to Clone/Copy Standard page for Accounts

Tags: clone

I want to built certail function which seems not possible by creating custom fields in acounts....so wanted to know if it is possible copying or cloning the Acounts page so that i can build my custom functions on top of it? any inputs please?

Question more in detail:

I have a dropdown list in Opportunity called 'Stages' and wish to have currency fields for 12 months I.E 12 fields corresponding to each month which displays the estimated weightage value. So whenever i choose a stage I need to consider the opportunity start date, the proposition value of the opportunity and number of days to calculate the estimated weightage and display it in the appropriate months. To do this the custom fields is not flexible and i wanted to see the fields updating as and when the stage is selected and not after an event like 'SAVE' . So viewing other possibilities i wish to know on how to copy the page of 'Opportunity' and build my custom features on top of it

Comment: Yes it is possible. You would do this with Visualforce. In the near future, Lightning Components should support this. But this question is really too vague to be more specific. Please read, the How To Ask page and maybe you can refine your question. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hi Peter - I've added more details on my requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, today, Salesforce is at a point of flux in custom UI development.

On the one hand, there is the tried and true way: Visualforce. There is a lot of documentation on how to take an existing page layout's look and feel and reproduce that in Visualforce.

Lightning Component Framework is our new custom UI technology. There are a number of advantages to using Lightning Components, not the least of which is this is how we at Salesforce are building user interfaces today. However LCF has not yet reached feature parity with Visualforce. What you can do with LCF is increasing each release, but there are still some things that will really need Visualforce.

Add into this mix that we are also in the midst of a big shift away from our old look and feel to a more modern look and feel, and this makes for a lot of moving parts.

The good part is that if you're going to use point and click, it will all work. But what you want to do, it is a tricky time to make this decision, and there are more factors than can be summed up in a relatively short SFSE answer. You're in for some prototyping, testing and discovery, I'm afraid.

1. See if Lightning Components can do what you want to do. (Since this will be evolving greatly in the near future, I'm hesitant to be specific here.)
2. If not, look to Visualforce. If you want the modern UI (Lightning Experience) build with Salesforce Lightning Design System CSS.
3. If you want the bog standard older "Salesforce Classic" UI, you're pretty safe with Visualforce, but you will want to factor in some technical debt project time when your implementation decides to pivot in the direction of the new UI.

Comment: Thkx Peter....I will look into the LCF. Regarding the " There is a lot of documentation on how to take an existing page layout's look and feel and reproduce that in Visualforce." -> can u suggest some docs please? i cudnt find one that can be of reference to my req

Comment: I created a simple VF page with a user input field using the standard controller for Product2. As in knowledge article 000005105 i insert my VF from page layout which is seen when i open one of the products. But when i edit the products i do not see my VF screen. I think if i can manage to bring my VF screen into the edit mode my issue would be managed, any inputs or thoughts on it please?

Comment: You'll need to build up the layout using the `apex:pageBlock` family of tags. They are pretty well documented. Start with the docs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockSection.htm. Have a go. when you get stuck...new question. Also look into how StandardController works. Cheers.